# Foundation: how to switch between small and medium reveal modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5. Somewhere in the footer I have theese two divs waiting to get opened as a reveal modal:

```
<div id="smallModal"  class="reveal-modal small"  data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"></div>
<div id="mediumModal" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"></div>
```

I use them to load content in it with Ajax. That works fine. 
Now on a big screen, it's enough to open a smallModal. If the screensize gets smaller (Tablets) the smallModal gets to small. Here I would need the mediumModal.

I use this code to open a smallModal:

```
<a href="somefile.php" data-reveal-id="smallModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">Open Modal</a>
```

I **don't** want to use `show-for-medium-only` or `show-for-large-up` CSS classes. Because in that case I have to write both links:

```
<a calss="show-for-medium-only" href="somefile.php" data-reveal-id="mediumModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">Open Modal</a>
<a calss="show-for-large-up"    href="somefile.php" data-reveal-id="smallModal"  data-reveal-ajax="true">Open Modal</a>
```

And I also **don't** want to open mediumModals for all screen sizes. The mediumModals are just to big on large screens.

Isn't there a way to let this do automaticly? If screensize is smaller than large: open all modals as mediumModal and if screen is big enough open them all as smallModal.
If the screen gets very small (Smartphones) Foundation switches by it self to full-screen-modals. Just like that but for medium screens and large-up.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate the two links into one and add an `id` attribute to the remaining link so that you can select it using javascript.

Create a new function to

- Check the window width and set a variable based on the result.

  - If it is greater then `768`, set the variable to 'smallModal'
  - If it is less then `768`, set the variable to 'mediumModal'
- Check the existing setting against the setting that it should be

  - If it is different, set the attribute to the desired setting
  - If it is the same, do nothing

Attach this function to the windows resize event using `window.onresize = function` without the brackets so that you pass the function reference and not the rest

Run the function once on page load.

<sub>**Note:** 768 is an arbitrary number, you can use whatever number you like.</sub>

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle-modal');

function changeToggle() {
    var reveal = window.innerWidth > 768 ? 'smallModal' : 'mediumModal'
    if(toggle.getAttribute('data-reveal-id')!=== reveal) {
        toggle.setAttribute('data-reveal-id',reveal);
    }
}

window.onresize = changeToggle;

changeToggle();
```